# Is it possible to use a button or slicer to select which measure appears in Values of a visualization?

Tags: powerbi

In short, I would like to have a matrix that is specific to one Value over time (ex. sales per month), with ability for a user to replace sales with units or margin by selecting a button or slicer.  I can conceive of a arse-backwards way to do this such as a complicated IF-based formula and data to support, but this seems like something that could be stock functionality that is presently outside of my knowledge base.  Thank you in advance for any and all input on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Define your different measures like `[sales]`, `[units]`, and `[margin]` and then write a measure that switches between them based on what `[metric]` you've chosen with your button/slicer.

```
SwitchValue =
VAR SelectedMetric = SELECTEDVALUE ( Metrics[metric] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        SelectedMetric,
        "Sales", [sales],
        "Units", [units],
        "Margin", [margin]
    )
```

This assumes you've created a table `Metrics` like this to use for your slicer:

```
metric
------
Sales
Units
Margin
```

---

If you want to format these separate measures differently, one workaround is to wrap each one in a `FORMAT` function specifying your desired format (either [pre-defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/pre-defined-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function) or [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/dax/custom-numeric-formats-for-the-format-function)). For example,

```
SWITCH(SelectedMetric,
    "Sales",  FORMAT([sales], "Currency"),
    "Units",  FORMAT([units], "0"),
    "Margin", FORMAT([margin], "0.00%")
)
```

The disadvantage of this is that these are all now text values (strings), which can make sorting behave not as expected. Also, if you choose to export your data, you'll have lost any precision beyond the decimal places you've formatted to.

Comment: Confirmed that this works beautifully!  Except for one issue - in the case of a selection from units, sales and margin, I have three distinct formats of data (whole number, currency, percentage).  I don't see a way to adjust the formatting dynamically - is there an option to do this via DAX?  Let me know if you prefer me to ask as a separate question and I can re-create.  Also on semi-related note, I was trying to figure out if it was possible to sort a matrix by a value that is not within the matrix itself (such as sorting margin data by unit / sales volume).

Comment: You can wrap a `FORMAT` function around each of those measures. E.g. `FORMAT([margin], "0.00%")` instead of just `[margin]`. I don't think you can sort by values not used in the matrix.

Comment: Ahh, excellent!  Want me to repost as a separate thread so you can get your point and it can be better-searchable for someone else with same question?

Comment: Nah, it mostly fits with this question. I'll edit in a note in my answer too.